# What is complexity of std::common_type?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, type-traits

I wrote my `std::common_type` implementation:

```
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct my_common_type {
  using type = typename my_common_type<Head, typename my_common_type<Tail...>::type>::type;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct my_common_type<T, U> {
  using type = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<U>())>;
};
```

With knowledge that this metafunction returns type from proposed to which we can convert the others in this case my implementation won't work:

```
struct Granny {};
struct Mother : Granny {};
struct Father : Granny {};
```

`my_common_type<Granny, Mother, Father>::type` will not compile but `std::common_type_t<Granny, Mother, Father>` will return `Granny` type.

Is std::common_type works on O(n!) when n is the count of types proposed(yeah, I know that it works on compilation time)?

Or maybe O(n^2)?

UPD:

`std::common_type_t<Mother, Father, Granny>` doesn't work. In which way common type are searched?

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: @tobias, I am interested in clang and g++.

Comment: Have you tried `std::common_type<Mother, Father, Granny>`? Did it work?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., hm. It doesn't work.

Comment: `common_type` is defined to work left-to-right. Your version works right-to-left which is why it gives different results.

Comment: @interjay, can you add an answer to close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When applying `common_type` to three or more template arguments, `common_type<T1, T2, R...>::type` is defined to be `common_type_t<C, R...>` where C is `common_type_t<T1, T2>`. If T1 and T2 don't have a common type then the `type` typedef doesn't exist.

This means that `common_type` is defined to work from left to right on its arguments, and it can be done in O(n). It also means that rearranging the order of arguments can lead to different results.

In your own implementation, you work from right to left, which is why you got different results.